# Привести число к определенному виду

Tags: python, pandas

Df

```
    Телефон
0  749578267921216406327
1  84951491991
2  79037481292
3  74992506983
4  84957975576
5  749567348106039156
```

Как оставить только первые 11 цифр в строке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант:

```
df["Телефон"] = df["Телефон"].str.slice(0, 11)
```

результат:

```
In [219]: df
Out[219]:
       Телефон
0  74957826792
1  84951491991
2  79037481292
3  74992506983
4  84957975576
5  74956734810
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df["Телефон"] = df["Телефон"].str[:11]

74956895325
84951491991
79037481292
79269431224
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]